# Calling One Form From Another

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use ShowDialog to display a pop up box from my aspx page then grab the return value from it. I created my form to be called but can't get it to register with my initial page. Here is all the code in my new form;

```
Partial Class MyForm
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

And the relevant code from my initial page;

```
Partial Class List
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim request As New MyForm
End Sub

End Class
```

But Visual Studio doesn't recognise `MyForm`. What am I doing wrong?

---

Not sure if they're relevant but here's the page declaration for my new page;

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MyForm.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="MyForm" %>
```

and for my original form;

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="../../../Site.master" 
CodeFile="List.aspx.vb" Inherits="List" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not display a pop up box in ASP.NET using ShowDialog the way you do in Windows Forms.
If you need to display a pop up in ASP.NET use [ASP.NET ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)  or [JQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Also, in ASP.NET you don't call a form as you are doing. You simply redirect to it. Check [HttpResponse.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)